# Search Script with 2 criteria. Google API and Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, criteriaquery

I have a form with 5 fields connected to a Google Spreadsheet. When my user input data in the first 2 fields the 3 other fields update according to the data of the Spreadsheet.
My script is working perfectly with one criteria but I need second criteria in order to update the 3 other fields.
My HTML :

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <HTML>
  <head>
<base target="_top">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>    
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
 <?!=include("page-css"); ?>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="container">    
    <div class="row">
       <div class="input-field col s12">
         <input id="ds" type="text" class="validate">
         <label for="ds">Contract Number</label>
       </div>          
    </div> 
    <div class="row">
       <div class="input-field col s12">
         <input id="pn" type="text" class="validate">
         <label for="pn">Number</label>
       </div>          
    </div> 
    <h5> RESULTS </h5>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input disabled id="est" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="est" class="active">Validity date from</label>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input disabled id="est1" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="est1" class="active">Expiry Date</label>
    </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input disabled id="est2" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="est2" class="active">Type</label>
    </div>
    </div>       
</div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <?!=include("page-js"); ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

My script have to do : Search value of "est", "est1", "est2" for "ds" AND "pn"

The script is :

```
     <script>

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
  var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
   });

   document.getElementById("ds").addEventListener("input",getEstimate)

function getEstimate(){
var contractNumber = document.getElementById("ds").value;
if(contractNumber.length === 8){
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(upadteEstimate).getDateStart(contractNumber);
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(upadteEstimate1).getDateExpiry(contractNumber);
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(upadteEstimate2).getInsurancePlan(contractNumber);
}  
}

function upadteEstimate(DateStart){
document.getElementById("est").value = DateStart;
M.updateTextFields();    

}

function upadteEstimate1(DateExpiry){
document.getElementById("est1").value = DateExpiry;
M.updateTextFields();    

}
 
function upadteEstimate2(InsurancePlan){
document.getElementById("est2").value = InsurancePlan;
M.updateTextFields();    

}   
</script>
```

I have tried a lot of things without success. If someone could give me some tips or advise, It will help a lot...
Thank you
J

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, I think that in your situation, it might be required to know the structure of data base for searching the values of `ds` and `pn`. In your script, it seems that `DateStart`, `DateExpiry` and `InsurancePlan` are returned using `contractNumber`. In this case, how do you want to do about the value of `pn`? Can I ask you about the detail of your current situation and your goal?

Comment: Hi ! What do ```updateTextFields```, ```getDateStart```, ```getDateExpiry``` and ```getInsurancePlan``` exactly do?